# Асимптотика функции sort(list) в ЯП Python

Tags: python-3.x, алгоритм, олимпиада, сложность, асимптотика

Видите ли, мне очень важна асимптотика данной функции.

Comment: Сложность: O(n * log(n))

Answer (score 1):

В `Python` используется [сортировка слиянием](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC).

В лучшем, среднем и худшем случае она работает за `O(n*log(n))`.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort https://bugs.python.org/file4451/timsort.txt